# Top align text and image within div

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

Here's the rendered html:

```
<div style="padding-left: 50px; vertical-align: middle;">
  <strong>NONE</strong>
  <img height="15" width="15" src="images/Checked.gif" alt="">
  <br>
  <span style="font-size: larger;">DEFAULT</span>
</div>
```

general css:

```
div {
  font-size:smaller;
  padding:5px 5px 0 0;
  float:left;
}
```

Here's what the design looks like in firebug:
[image]

I would like the text **NONE** to align at the top, just the way the image (checkbox) is aligned. Any ideas on how to do this with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align: middle` doesn't do what you think it does.

```
<div style="padding-left: 50px;">
  <strong style="float: left;">NONE</strong>
  <img height="15" width="15" src="images/Checked.gif" alt="">
  <br>
  <span style="font-size: larger;">DEFAULT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want a fast way to vertically center, set a height like `100px` and give the element a `line-height` of `100px`. This vertically centers one line of text. A `line-height` of `50px` does two, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- Since you know the height of your image, to get the exact alignment you want, try setting a `line-height`.  You can set it at 15px or 1 (just 1, no unit), and see which you prefer.
- Change your value for vertical-align.  It's meant to control the vertical alignment of two inline (or inline-block) items next to each other.  Which is what you have when you have `strong` next to `img`, it's just that `middle` doesn't look the way you want.  Other values that work reasonably well cross-browser are `baseline`, `top`, `bottom` and sometimes `text-top` or `text-bottom`.
- Beyond that, you can set both the `img` and the `strong` to `block` and use `float`, `height`, and `padding`.

Examples:

```
<div style="padding-left: 50px; line-height: 15px;">
  <strong>NONE</strong>
  <img height="15" width="15" src="images/Checked.gif" alt="">
  <br>
  <span style="font-size: larger;">DEFAULT</span>
</div>

<div style="padding-left: 50px; vertical-align: top;">
  <strong>NONE</strong>
  <img height="15" width="15" src="images/Checked.gif" alt="">
  <br>
  <span style="font-size: larger;">DEFAULT</span>
</div>
```

Others have already down an example with floats.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the line height on the top is going to conform to however high your image is. To compensate, you can put the "none" text in a block element, and then set your alignment in there. Here would be an example:

```
<div style="padding-left: 50px; vertical-align: middle;">
  <div style="height:15px; width:50px; float:left;">NONE</div>
  <img style="height:15px; width:15px; float:left;" src="images/Checked.gif" alt="" />
  <br style="clear:both;" />
  <span style="font-size:larger;">DEFAULT</span>
</div>
```

From here you can play with the padding and alignment within that div around the none text.

Answer (score 0):

These answers didn't work for me, here's how I got it working...

```
<div style="line-height:0px;">
  <span style="vertical-align:middle;">test</span>
  <img src="myimage.png" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
</div>
```

give the container element (in my example, the `<div>`) element a line-height attribute value of 0px; then everything you want on the line should have a `vertical-align:middle`; style applied.

Tested in Chrome, FF, IE7+...